# How to generate a gaussian map with an effective y for an Equator Bias weighing?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I'm trying to add an Equator Bias weighing to an image, for that I'm using a Gaussian distribution and generate a weighing map to fuse it with the image. The following code is used to generate the weights map:

```
function map = gaussian_map(height, width)
    if (width>8000)
        density = 8*height;
    elseif (width>4000 & width<=8000)
        density = 8*height;
    elseif (width>2000 & width<=4000)
       density = 4*height;
    else
    density = 2*height;
    end

beta = height/2;

for x = 1:height
    for y = 1:width
        map(x,y) = exp(-(x-beta)*(x-beta)/density);
    end
   end
end
```

Which gives something like this :

[image]

**Update:**

As we can see the distribution starts with `y = 0`. What I need is that this later starts let say `y = 0.3` and all weights must be within `[0, 1]`, something that should look like this:

[image]

I've done some googling but I couldn't find much information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So all you want is `map = map+0.3`? i.e. raise the entire graph with `0.3`?

Comment: I've just tried what you proposed, and it does starts from `y=0.3` but its neglected the interval from `[0, 0.3[` and gives weights greater than 1, which is not exactly what I need.

Comment: @Adriaan I've updated the question.

Comment: That's not mathematically possible, because the integral over the function (i.e. the area underneath the line) will then be larger than 1, which is in violation of what a Gaussian is. `map  = 0.7*map+0.3` should do this though.

Comment: Ok, I see, is it possible to do so using something else?

Comment: As I mentioned: programmatically that's no problem, just do what I mentioned in my last comment. It might not make mathematical sense, but I can't comment to that, not knowing your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204118/discussion-between-sendjasni-and-adriaan).